# How to set parent state from FlatList component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `PaymentMethodsScreen` screen. On this screen there is a `FlatList` with `PaymentCardItem` components inside. And there is a checkbox inside the `PaymentCardItem`. When this checkbox checked I would like to update **selectedCardToken** state of `PaymentMethodsScreen`. But unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried to pass props but I was doing it wrong. Here is my code (without passing props).

How can I achieve that? Thank you very much for your helps.

```
const PaymentCardItem = ({ family,  association, bin_number, token, isSelected }) => (
    <View>
        <RadioCheckbox 
            selected={ isSelected }
            onPress={ () => this.setSelectedCardToken(token) // Something wrong here } 
            />
        <Text>{family}, {association}</Text>
        <Text>{bin_number}**********</Text>
    </View>
);

const PaymentMethodsScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const {state} = useContext(AuthContext);

    const [cardList, setCardList] = useState(null) // This stores card list data from API request
    const [selectedCardToken, setSelectedCardToken] = useState('test token')


    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <PaymentCardItem
            bin_number={item.bin_number} 
            family={item.family} 
            association={item.association} 
            token={ item.token }
            isSelected={ (selectedCardToken == item.token) }
        />
      );



  return (
        <SafeAreaView>
                        <View>

                                <FlatList
                                    data={cardList}
                                    renderItem={renderItem}
                                    keyExtractor={item => item.alias}
                                />
                        </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

add onPress prop to PaymentCardItem:

```
// PaymentMethodsScreen

    <PaymentCardItem
        onPress={() => setSelectedCardToken(item.token)}
    >
```

I don't know how the PaymentCardItem component is structured, but generally you should add onPress prop on the TouchableOpacity in the component or whatever is your onPress handler:

```
// PaymentCardItem component

    <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={() => props.onPress()}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down the handler function which gets called on checkbox being checked or unchecked to your `PaymentCardItem` component.

You can also pass `setSelectedCardToken` directly, but in case you have some extra logic before you update state, it's better to have a handler for more readability.

So, the code will be like below.

```js
const PaymentMethodsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const [cardList, setCardList] = useState(null) // This stores card list data from API request
    const [selectedCardToken, setSelectedCardToken] = useState('test token')

    const handleCardTokenSelection = (isTokenSelected) => {
      if(isTokenSelected) { 
        setSelectedCardToken(); // whatever logic you have
      } else {
        setSelectedCardToken(); // whatever logic you have
      }
    }

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <PaymentCardItem
            bin_number={item.bin_number} 
            family={item.family} 
            association={item.association} 
            token={ item.token }
            isSelected={ (selectedCardToken == item.token) }
            handleCardTokenSelection={handleCardTokenSelection}
        />
      );



  return (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <View>
            <FlatList
              data={cardList}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={item => item.alias}
            />
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
  );
};


const PaymentCardItem = ({ family,  association, bin_number, token, isSelected, handleCardTokenSelection }) => (
    <View>
        <RadioCheckbox 
            selected={ isSelected }
            onPress={handleCardTokenSelection} 
            />
        <Text>{family}, {association}</Text>
        <Text>{bin_number}**********</Text>
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state for `PaymentCardItem` not for the whole Flatlist, to show the item is selected.

I think you update the `PaymentCardItem` component to something like the below code(You can update the logic as per requirement)

```
class PaymentCardItem extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectedCardToken: "", isSelected: false};
  }

  setSelectedCardToken=(token)=>{
    if(selectedCardToken == token){
      this.setState({
        selectedCardToken: token,
        isSelected: true
     })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { family,  association, bin_number, token  }=this.props;
    const { isSelected } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <RadioCheckbox 
            selected={ isSelected }
            onPress={ () => this.setSelectedCardToken(token)
            />
        <Text>{family}, {association}</Text>
        <Text>{bin_number}**********</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```